# Update + where not exist

Tags: mysql, where, exists

once again, I come here for your rescue.

how can I improve a query like this for a table with 20 million rows? 
I'm trying to update a table, by using the date and getting the first date of attendance for each student

```
update student_activity c join 
(select * from  student_activity a
where not exists 
        (select * from student_activity b where a.student_id = b.student_id 
                                            and a.class_type = b.class_type
                                            and a.date > b.date)) r
on r.student_id = c.student_id and c.class_type = r.class_type
set c.first_attendance = c.date
;
```

Comment: It's a very complicated way to get the `MIN(date)`.

Answer (score 1):

Your query can be collapsed to the single `JOIN` without subselects:

```
UPDATE      student_activity AS c 
  LEFT JOIN student_activity AS b ON c.student_id = b.student_id 
                                 AND c.class_type = b.class_type
                                 AND c.date > b.date
 WHERE b.date IS NULL 
   SET c.first_attendance = c.date
;
```

I hope your table `student_activity` have the index (student_id, class_type, date)

Comment: This didn't work. I want a situation whereby if there are multiple entries for a student, the first_attendance will display all entries for a student as the min date

Comment: I've just simplify your query to avoid redundant operations. If you want the query doing something specific you should formulate what exactly you want.